# What Plasma versions will be available within 18.04 LTS?

Tags: 18.04, kubuntu, lts, versions, plasma-5

I like Kubuntu 18.04 a lot, it is very stable and maybe the best Linux I ever used. I am facing some minor problems (like [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1110555/47206) and [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/1110494/47206)) that are possibly fixed in the newer versions of Plasma (5.13), but I have no intention of leaving the LTS version (I have already tested Kubuntu 18.10). I like the idea of using latest software, but from experience I can say that while it is a good idea for many applications, it is not the best as far as desktop environments are concerned.

Therefore I am curious if and when Kubuntu 18.04 LTS will pass to a Plasma version above 5.12.

As 18.10 uses Plasma 5.13, will the release of the 19.04 normally involve the passing of 18.04 LTS to (at least) 5.13?

Comment: Whatever I've read indicates that Kubuntu 18.04 will stay on 5.12 for its entire life.

Comment: @DKBose - that is not surprising, with non-LTS releases serving the purpose of testing newer desktop versions before their integration in the next LTS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

plasma-workspace appears to be updating in 18.04 only in the 5.12 version series. plasma-workspace version is either 5.12.4 in the 18.04 bionic/universe repository or 5.12.7 in the 18.04 bionic-updates/universe repository. plasma-workspace version is 5.13.5 in the default Ubuntu 18.10 repositories, 5.14.5 in the default Ubuntu 19.04 repositories, 5.16.5 in the default Ubuntu 19.10 repositories and 5.18.4 in the default Ubuntu 20.40 repositories.